# Full Image Display in Android (AlertDialog)

Tags: android

I've this pice of code that amplifies the image, this puts the image inside a layout and display it.
The problem is that it works for some pictures, but others the error that this returns is **null** but why, if it works for some why doesn't work for all?

```
    public static void ImagemEmGrande(boolean state, Activity a, int layout, String url) throws MalformedURLException, IOException{
        ProgressBar.progressBar(state, a, layout);
        ImageView iv = (ImageView)ProgressBar.view.findViewById(R.id.id_iv_preview);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(url).getContent());
        iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        iv.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
    }
```

"ProgressBar" (this works fine)

```
private static Activity activity;
private static AlertDialog.Builder builder;
private static AlertDialog alerta;
public static View view;

public static void progressBar(boolean state, Activity a, int layout){

    activity = a;

    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
    if (state){         
         LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
         builder.setView(view = inflater.inflate(layout, null));
         builder.create();
         alerta = builder.show();
    } else {
        alerta.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has  `BitmapFactory.decodeStream()`. For some images you have `BitmapFactory` can not convert them to bitmaps. So, `BitmapFactory` returns `null` and setting image to null is the same as show nothing. Try see if those are real bitmaps in a browser.

Go to the `url` you have in `(InputStream)new URL(url).getContent()` in a browser or somehow and see what's in there

Comment: i can display them in tablelayout but some of them when i  click and open the alert dialog to see them bigger it wont show! is empty and returns me to catch, saying null (i associate this null to the imageview < maybe)

Comment: If you can display them in one place in android and can not in an other place you have to debug. Probably null somehow comes to that other place.